# Using Google Cloud Endpoints for Android and ADT

Tags: android, adt, google-cloud-endpoints

I'm using ADT (Eclipse) to write my Android App.  I already have my Google Cloud Endpoints API coded and tested.  Now I need to have my Android app connect to my endpoints API.

I've already created my Client library and Discovery document.

But I can't find any information on what to import, and how to actually make my API calls, as well as what to do with the Discovery document (besides generating it).  All the info by Google on consuming endpoints for Android are specific to Android Studio:

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/endpoints/consume_android

Does that mean ADT is unable to connect to endpoints?

If you could point me to instructions for an ADT Android project making endpoints calls, that would really be great.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There are tutorials available for this on the web. One set of tutorials, starting from writing Endpoints to clients (Android + Web) and securing them is covered over here : http://rominirani.com/2014/01/10/google-cloud-endpoints-tutorial-part-1/

Comment: Romin, thank you.  I was looking at this yesterday.  Unfortunately I used Python to write my API and the Android Client library zip file structure is different.  I don't have an src folder under the root of the zip.  I may have to redo it in Java.  Nice blog post, very clear.  Thanks!